# Internal variables from tested function not visible in test function

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I'm trying to figure out why the test fails – probably because the value of security  token variable, is not passed into mocha test. I don't know how to pass it. All  this  tutorials  about  testing works only  with  return 'Hello World' strings, but there is nothing practical. And can someone advise me, what else i can test in this type of function, and how.

Original function:

```
export function getUserDetails() {
  let securityToken = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sectoken'));
  return reqwest({
    url: 'http://api.mywebsite.com/api/Account/UserInfo',
    method: 'GET',
    crossOrigin: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${securityToken.access_token}`,
    },
  }).then((response) => JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Here is my test for this function:

```
//getUserDetails
describe('getUserDetails', () => {
  it('Should return user details of curently logged in user',() => {

    getUserDetails().then(function(response){
      console.log(securityToken.access_token);
      response.toExist().toBeA('string');
    });
  });
});
```

In result I'm receiving error:

```
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0) getUserDetails Should return user details of curently logged in user FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of null
            at getUserDetails (tests.webpack.js:7589:48)
            at Context.<anonymous> (tests.webpack.js:14005:31)
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0.115 secs / 0.056 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the `securityToken` too. Otherwise it will be inaccessible outside the function.

```
export function getUserDetails() {
  let securityToken = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('sectoken'));
  return [securityToken, reqwest({
    url: 'http://api.mywebsite.com/api/Account/UserInfo',
    method: 'GET',
    crossOrigin: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${securityToken.access_token}`,
    },
  }).then((response) => JSON.stringify(response))];
}
```

Then in the test function:

```
getUserDetails().then(function(securityToken, response){
  console.log(securityToken.access_token);
  response.toExist().toBeA('string');
});
```

Comment: Hi. I have try your suggestion and,  when i run the test, its still throwing me errors

Comment: @KrzysztofKoch Jakie konkretnie błędy?

Comment: Nadal nie widzi zmiennej  access_token.  Rzuca mi bledem:    TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of null

Comment: @KrzysztofKoch A jak dasz `console.log(securityToken)` do tej funkcji `getUserDetails` to co dostajesz?

Comment: //getUserDetails
describe('getUserDetails', () => {
  it('Should return user details of curently logged in user',() => {
      getUserDetails().then(function(securityToken, response){
      console.log(securityToken);
        console.log(securityToken.access_token);
        response.toExist().toBeA('string');
    });
  });
});
Wyrzuca:

Comment: Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0) getUserDetails Should return user details of curently logged in user FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'access_token' of null
            at getUserDetails (tests.webpack.js:7640:48)
            at Context.<anonymous> (tests.webpack.js:14055:31)
Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 6 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0.09 secs / 0.036 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

Comment: Wyglada na to ze  funkcja loginUser w tescie,  nie tworzy tokenu po zalogowaniu, zrobilem  console.log w srodku funkcji getUserDetails, nie w tescie, i wyrzuca null

Answer (score 0):

To make the test  working, i had to call first loginUser function on  each of tested functions, and return token into it:

```
 //getUserDetails
    describe('getUserDetails', () => {
      it('Should return user details of curently logged in user',() => {
        loginUser(rooturl,'abc@abc.pl', 'Password!1232').then(function(token){
          getUserDetails().then(function(userDetails){
            expect(userDetails).toExist();
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Thanks guys!